# Problem with moving other elements during hover selector

Tags: css, hover, selector

I would like to solve my problem with hover selector. I have a classic content with 3 columns (Icon from font awesome, h2 and p).

I want to make this icon bigger when I hover it but when I 'm doing it other elements are moving down when icon is growing.

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center text-center">
            <div class="col-4">
                <i class="fas fa-desktop pb-5"></i>
                <h2>Fully Responsive</h2>
                <p class="lead">This theme will look great on any device, no matter the size!</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4">
                <i class="fas fa-layer-group pb-5"></i>
                <h2>Bootstrap 4 Ready</h2>
                <p class="lead">Featuring the latest build of the new Bootstrap 4 framework!</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4">
                <i class="far fa-check-circle pb-5"></i>
                <h2>Easy to use</h2>
                <p class="lead">Ready to use with your own content, or customize the source files!</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You could make your i tag's height bigger, so when you hover and change font size of your icon (as long as it stays within the height) nothing will move.

Comment: Actually in CSS I only have font-size for i tag's and bigger font-size for hovered i tag's. Should I add this height there ?

Comment: You can/should add height. The only thing you should change, for that to work, is display property. Display: block, would do the job.

Comment: I add another div to i tag's and this div has a height. It's working. Thank you!

Comment: Can you please mark my answer as correct beacuse of other devs with same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make your i tag's height bigger, so when you hover and change font size of your icon (as long as it stays within the height) nothing will move.